Flutter Getx route argument data is lost when hot reload
Question might be misleading, but I'm currently working on a project where I use Get.toNamed a lot and I'm sending some data every time. But, when I hot reload the changes I get
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type `int` 

and I'm changing route with
onTap: () {
    print(_sliderValue);
    Get.toNamed('/stations/detail/booking', arguments: {
        'duration': _sliderValue,
    });
},

Edit:
As I have mentioned, I'm using Stateless Widget to for that screen, so the code I have is:
class ConnectorScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ConnectorScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Map<String, dynamic> arguments =
        Get.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
    final Connector connector = arguments['connectors'];

which gives error that type 'Null' is not a subtype of type Connector once I hot reload.
Is there any proper way of not losing data while routing between pages or hot reload?

Im always using Get.toNamed to send arguments but never found issue like this soo maybe you can try this
You can route to page by SecondPage.show(somethingId : 'id#0');
class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static String get name => '/second-page';

  const SecondPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static Future<void> show({
    required String somethingId,
  }) async {
    await Get.toNamed(
      name,
      arguments: {
        'somethingId': somethingId,
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   ....
  }

and in controller
class SecondPageController extends GetxController {
  @override
  void onInit() async {
    somethingId.value = Get.arguments['somethingId'] ?? '';

    super.onInit();
  }

  final somethingId = ''.obs;
}


This may be because the variable is private with the underscore.
Try sliderValue  instead of _sliderValue

No, that is not the case indeed. If you send the data with route using arguments and if you hot reload that data is lost.

you lose the data in the /stations/detail/booking view right ?
try to call your argument on initState of the same page

I'm usually calling it inside the return context, but I will also try that out. I think you are right.

I am using mostly Stateless Widgets, so initState would not be an option by the way. I have edited my question.

Please update your answer.
